# INSTEAD OF AND COMPOUND INTEGER

Tags: plsql

C.  Create an INSTEAD OF row trigger on EMP_VU that increases the current count for a department by 1 if a new employee is added and subtracts 1 from the count for a department if an employee is deleted

```
create or replace trigger count_trigger
instead of insert or delete on emp_vu 
begin 
if deleting then 
update dept_count 
set count_emps = count_emps - 1 
where dept_id = :OLD.department_id ;
elsif inserting then 
update dept_count 
set count_emps = count_emps + 1 
where dept_id = :NEW.department_id ; 
end if ; 
end ;
/
```

D.  Look at the counts for all departments in DEPT_COUNT. Test to see if your trigger fires correctly by inserting a row into EMP_VU. Look at the count for the department of the new employee. Delete a row from EMP_VU. Look at the count for the department where the employee was just deleted.

```
SELECT * FROM dept_count;

INSERT INTO emp_vu VALUES (606, 'Sillins', 90);

DELETE FROM emp_vu WHERE employee_id = 606;
```

Excuse me is there anyone help to repair this query?

Comment: Repair? Why? What's wrong with it?

Comment: I can't modify the row both of table

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Please provide all the following: Table and view definitions, (ddl), sample data, expected results, all as text - **no images**. Also show the result current of your current queries and why that is not correct.